# CryptographicException: Unknown Error '80007005'. when calling RSACryptoServiceProvider.Decrypt() in .Net Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, rsa

I am trying to use the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` to encrypt/decrypt. Encrypting works fine, but the `Decrypt` method throws an exception with the message:

Unknown Error '80007005'.

This is the code:

```
Byte[] plainData = encoding.GetBytes(plainText);
Byte[] encryptedData;
RSAParameters rsap1;
Byte[] decryptedData;
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
   encryptedData = rsa1.Encrypt(plainData, false);
   rsap1 = rsa1.ExportParameters(false);
}

using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
   rsa2.ImportParameters(rsap1);
   decryptedData = rsa2.Decrypt(encryptedData, false);
}

decryptedText = encoding.GetString(decryptedData, 0, decryptedData.Length);
```

Is anyone aware of a workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the code! I guess I do not need to specify a container after all...

```
Byte[] plainData = encoding.GetBytes(plainText);
Byte[] encryptedData;
Byte[] decryptedData;
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    RSAParameters rsap1 = rsa1.ExportParameters(false);

    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rsa2.ImportParameters(rsap1);
        encryptedData = rsa2.Encrypt(plainData, false);
    }

    decryptedData = rsa1.Decrypt(encryptedData, false);
}

decryptedText = encoding.GetString(decryptedData, 0, decryptedData.Length);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
rsap1 = rsa1.ExportParameters(false);
```

By passing false to this method, you're choosing to not export the private key. Without the private key it will be difficult to decrypt the data. Try passing true to the export method.

Comment: Exporting the key along with the data renders RSA useless. Besides, the encryptor is likely not even in possession of the private key.

Answer (score -2):

When using RSA you need to understand the basics of key management. You did not specify what key container to use during encryption. What key do you expect to be used? The default user key? The machine key? Do you understand what the default user key and the machine keys *are* ? Not to mention the obvious question of *why* do you encrypt *anything* with RSA? RSA encryption is used *solely* for encrypting session keys, and there are dedicated key exchange protocols that take care of this out-of-the-box (stream oriented like TLS or document oriented like S/MIME). You should use one of these out-of-the-box protocols and not roll your own encryption scheme. You **will** screw up key management, that is guaranteed.

When you attempt to decrypt, does the decryptor has possession of the private key corresponding to the public key used during encryption?

See:

- [How to: Store Asymmetric Keys in a Key Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tswxhw92%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)
- [Encrypting Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as0w18af%28VS.80%29.aspx)
- [Decrypting Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te15te69%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Note that these are just simple code samples in MSDN and should never be used by anyone without a very deep understanding of cryptography, and specially key management.

I recommend you look into using a high level class like [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) for encrypting data exchanges. For a document storage encryption scheme you better use the OS facilities or rely on [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229741%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class. Again, do not roll your own encryption unless you *really* know what you're doing (in which case you wouldn't be asking questions here).