# RSA Decryption doesn't work - Unknown Error '80007005'

Tags: vb.net, compact-framework, rsa

I've worked with .NET's RSA implementation before without any trouble, but now I need to do some decryption on Windows Mobile 6. Normally I load the key using `FromXmlString`, but since that isn't in Compact Framework I tried this way. The variables `PublicKeyMod` and `PublicKeyExponent` are the strings in Modulus and Exponent in the XML I'd have used in `FromXLMString`. Decrypt is throwing the exception "Unknown Error '80007005'". Any idea why?

```
        Using stream_reader As New StreamReader(application_path + "\Mobile.lic")

            Dim enc_bytes(CInt(stream_reader.BaseStream.Length - 1)) As Byte 

            stream_reader.BaseStream.Read(enc_bytes, 0, CInt(stream_reader.BaseStream.Length))

            Using rsa_provider = New RSACryptoServiceProvider()
                Dim rsa_params As New RSAParameters()

                rsa_params.Modulus = System.Convert.FromBase64String(PublicKeyMod)
                rsa_params.Exponent = System.Convert.FromBase64String(PublicKeyExponent)

                rsa_provider.ImportParameters(rsa_params)

                Dim dec_bytes = rsa_provider.Decrypt(enc_bytes, False)

                Dim expiration_date As Date = New Date(System.BitConverter.ToInt64(dec_bytes, 0))
            End Using

        End Using
```

Comment: That's indeed an unknown error.  Sure it isn't 80070005?

Comment: @HansPassant Yep, just double checked! I can understand the misconception though, what with it being unknown. Error 80070005 is quite known

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2954292/1070452

Comment: @Plutonix I saw that, but it doesn't help with my situation

Comment: You cannot perform decryption with just the modulus and (public) exponent, you should be able to encrypt, but you will need to correctly populate the other members of the `RSAParameters` structure in order to use the `Decrypt()` method.